# Running a Numerical Simulation on a System of Differential Equations with unique initial conditions

Tags: programming, differential-equations, numerics, simulation

I have a system of differential equations as follows:

```
β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i,t],{t,2}]=M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i,t]])+τ[Θ[i+1,t],Θ[i,t]], (*for i=1*)
β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i,t],{t,2}]=M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i,t]])+τ[Θ[i-1,t],Θ[i,t]]+τ[Θ[i+1,t],Θ[i,t]], (*for i between 1 and n-1*)
β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i,t],{t,2}]=M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i,t]])+τ[Θ[i-1,t],Θ[i,t]], (*for i=n*)
```

Basically, what the equation describes is a series of coupled oscillators from `0` to `n`, with the `i^th` oscillator being connected to the `(i-1)^th` and `(i+1)^th` ones with a spring. `τ[Θ[j],Θ[i]]` describes the torque exerted by the `j^th` oscillator on the `i^th`.

**Edit**: My initial conditions for the systems are as follows.

- Initially, at time `t=0`, all the oscillators have:

  - an angular position of 0, that is, `Θ[i,0]=0 for all i from 0 to n`
  - and an angular velocity of 0, that is `D[Θ[i,t],{t,1}]=0 at t=0 for all i from 0 to n`
- Now, what I do next is to apply a force on the first oscillator causing it to accelerate and follow a certain path of motion over a specific initial time interval. For example, the force that I apply could cause it to complete to full rounds from time `t=0 to 20`; that is, the `Θ[0,t]=t/10*2π from t=0 to t=20`. As I apply this force, (some of) the other oscillators will move too as the first oscillator will exert a force on them through the spring which connects the oscillators.
- Finally, after time `t=20`, I no longer apply an external force on any of the oscillators and just allow it to oscillate based on the relations found in the differential equations.

If you're interested to see all the function definitions and the constants, they can be found below:

```
(* providing values for all our variables. these variables describe one particular set of coupled oscillators *)
M=0.1;
L=0.2;
β=1;
μ=1;
k=100;
η=0.3;
γ=0.2;
α=1;
g=9.81
(* defining the torque τ. funcf and funcg are only used to make the expression for τ simpler.*)
funcg=(1-η/(2(1-Cos[#1-#2])+(γ/α)^2)^0.5)&;
funcf=#+Abs[#]&;
τ=Sin[#1-#2]*k*L^2*funcf[funcg[#1,#2]]&;
```

**Edit**: Since I was solving a physics question, I forgot to state that what I meant by `g` in the equations was the gravitational acceleration on earth 9.81 and nothing related to the function `g` which I was using as an intermediate function to make my expression of `τ` less complicated. I've modified this by writing the function g as `funcg`.

After some work, I realized that the method suggested below of using `nodes` helped to simplify the code a great deal. Thanks, @Spawn1701D.

Comment: @Nasser sorry for rushing off the question. I hope it's more understandable now with the edits, especially the part about the initial condition.

Comment: If it isn't, please tell me; i'm quite sure a lot of people were confused with the initial phrasing of the question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the while loop? I assume that you create the grid with it but this can be easily done with the Table command for instance.

Comment: g is a two-variable function on your system looks like a constant can you correct that?

Comment: Vincent, if you are happy with @Spawn1701D 's answer, you should upvote it and - after waiting a reasonable number of days - even "accept" it (put a green mark on the answer), if nothing better arrives. So far,after 12 hours,  you have acknowledged Spawn1701D's valuable answer only "in words" in your question, but not upvoted it and Spawn1701D's only upvote, so far, is mine. Don't you want to upvote him?

Comment: @VincentTjeng: I think your question still needs some work: the equations are presumably still not correct (e.g. `Mg` should progably be `M*g` or `M g`), the comments miss a `*)` and the part about the initial/boundary conditions is still not clear. Isn't the angle of the first oscillator a fixed function so that it isn't a dependent variable anymore? You'll still need to fix the initial conditions for the others, then. If you have a solution involving `While`, why don't you post it so we have something to start with?

Comment: @magma thank you for the reminder. I didn't feel that it was fair to accept the answer since the original question wasn't phrased properly, and thus there was some confusion as to the symbol `g`. With my rephrased question, the way in which `g` is written in his answer isn't aligned with what I actually need. I've voted his answer up as useful, nevertheless.

Comment: @AlbertRetey, thanks for the feedback. I've modified those aspects of the equation, and hopefully my explanation for the boundary conditions are clearer.

Comment: First of all this is a system of n ODEs of order 2 for n unknown functions so two initial conditions are necessary. I assume that you give two different problems one that all start with  0 angular position and velocity and a second where you give the motion of a *boundary* node (Θ[0]). For the first problem I think its obvious that all the nodes will stay still for every t. For the second you have to add that *external force* to the first node for n=1. Hence, some more editing is needed ...

Comment: @VincentTjeng: I'm still not sure whether I understand your initial conditions correct: If what you are saying is that the angle of the boundary node is a predefined "forced" function, then I think you'd best split your total time interval into two parts: for the first part solve the system of `n-1` oscillators and `Θ[0,t]=t/10*2π` fixed (`Θ[0,t]` then isn't a dependent variable anymore). Then use the final states of that solution as initial conditions of another call to `NDSolve` for the full system with `n` oscillators for `20<t<tmax`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Albert Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I've upvoted your comment so it appears above the fold.

Comment: @Spawn1701D actually, for a system of n ODEs of order 2 for n unknown functions, 2n initial conditions would be necessary. Does Albert's last comment clarify the situation for you?

Comment: @VincentTjeng sorry I meant two conditions for each equation of the system. Still my main question is about the Θ[0] the external force, shouldn't this be included in the first node (Θ[1])? Right now the system as is with these initial conditions  will remain at rest for every t!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works with the definitions you gave and does what I understand you try to do:

```
n = 10;

fullSystem = Join[
  {
    β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i][t],{t,2}] == M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i][t]]) + τ[Θ[i+1][t],Θ[i][t]]
  } /. i -> 0,
  Table[
     β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i][t],{t,2}] 
     == 
     M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i][t]]) + τ[Θ[i-1][t],Θ[i][t]] + τ[Θ[i+1][t],Θ[i][t]], 
     {i,n-1}
  ],
  {
    β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i][t],{t,2}] == M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i][t]]) + τ[Θ[i-1][t],Θ[i][t]]
  } /. i -> n
]

Θfixed = Function[{t}, t/10*2*Pi]

sysFirstPart = Rest[fullSystem] /. Θ[_?(# == 0 &)] -> Θfixed

initFirstPart = Table[{Θ[i][0] == 0,Derivative[1][Θ[i]][0] == 0}, {i, 1, n}]

solFirstPart = NDSolve[
  Flatten[{sysFirstPart, initFirstPart}],
  Table[Θ[i], {i,n}], {t, 0, 20}, MaxSteps -> 100000
]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[Θ[i][t],{i,0,n}] /. solFirstPart], {t, 0, 20}]

initSecondPart = Join[
  {Θ[0][20] == Θfixed[20], Derivative[1][Θ[0]][20] == Derivative[1][Θfixed][20]},
  Thread[
      Table[Θ[i][20],{i,n}] 
      == 
      Table[Θ[i][20] /. solFirstPart[[1]],{i,n}]
  ],
  Thread[
      Table[Derivative[1][Θ[i]][20],{i,n}] 
      == 
      Table[Derivative[1][Θ[i]][20] /. solFirstPart[[1]],{i,n}]
  ]
]

solSecondPart = NDSolve[
  Flatten[{fullSystem, initSecondPart}],
  Table[Θ[i],{i,0,n}], {t,20,30}, MaxSteps -> 100000
  ]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[Θ[i][t],{i,0,n}] /. solSecondPart],{t,20,30}]
```

I have changed the naming of the variables slightly from `Θ[i,t]` to `Θ[i][t]` which makes some of the manipulations somewhat simpler, you might have a look at this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19053/169) why I think it is a good idea to be somewhat pedantic about how to name things. Other than that I'm solving the system in two parts: for the time interval `0<=t<=20` I'm solving without the first (`i==0`) oscillator and insert the forced angle for which I have defined the function `Θfixed`. Then I determine the values of `Θ[i][t]` and their derivatives at the end of that time interval from that solution `solFirstPart` and use these as the initial conditions `initSecondPart` for the remaining time span for which I chose `20<=t<=30`. For that second time interval I solve the full system, now including the equation and angle-position of the first oscillator. You could, if necessary, use any of the techniques mentioned in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/169) to "concatenate" the two solutions into one. It should also be no problem to combine this solution with the more elegant way to define the system with the `nodes` function that was given in another answer by Spawn1701D.

With version 9 it might be possible to solve the above in one call to `NDSolve` by making use of the new `WhenEvent`: I think you would need to reformulate your problem at least for the first oscillator so it uses only first derivatives of angle `Θ[0][t]` and angular velocity `vΘ[0][t]`. Then it should be possible to switch between the two parts in both the differential equations for `Θ[0][t]` and for `vΘ[0][t]` with a `WhenEvent`. I haven't tried this but if the OP or anyone else is interested and finds time to try that I'd be very interested if `NDSolve` will accept and solve such a system.

**Note:** For most applications I would expect such a one-stage solution using `WhenEvent` to be more complicated and probably less performant than the two-stage solution shown, but there might be cases where it is to be favoured, e.g. when one wants to couple such a system to other equations...

Comment: Hi @Albert, thank you for the answer. I'll try to see whether `NDSolve` accepts a system as you suggested. First, though, could you help me understand how the function `Θ[i][t]` allows `i` to be a parameter and `t` to be a variable? For my code, I ended up using a fudge where I named the functions `Θi[t]` instead, which is way less elegant than your solution.

Comment: @VincentTjeng: there is no magic in using expressions like `Θ[i]` as variable names for `NDSolve`, which only serve as unique labels. `NDSolve` will accept certain expressions besides pure Mathematica symbols as well. You just must ensure such expressions don't evaluate (that is, there are no definitions for them). As you have found, that can makes things a lot more elegant. You can even nest that pattern: `NDSolve` will happily accept expression like `x[1][3]` or `x["body1"][4][2]` as variable names. Other things it accepts are e.g. `Subscript[x,1]`, `Subscript["x","1"]` or even just `"x"`...

Comment: thanks, that opens the possibilities for my naming of variables a lot.

Comment: why does the code in this bit require one to write it as `Θ[_?(# == 0 &)]`, rather than simply writing `Θ[0]`?

Comment: @VincentTjeng: It isn't necessary in this specific case, it's more a general measure of precaution: pattern matching with numeric quantities has some pitfalls, c.f. `MatchQ[Θ[0] // N, Θ[0]]`, and my complicated pattern here is a leftover from an intermediate state with a `N` somewhere that I did remove lateron. Also depending on how that `0.` was generated it might be something slightly differing from an "exact" `0.`, which `Θ[_?(# == 0 &)]` would also take care of (unlike e.g. `Θ[0|0.]`).

Comment: Thank you! Why I asked you this is that some modified code that I tried to write couldn't work until I rewrote the code as you suggested in your answer, as in `Θ[_?(# == 0 &)]`, so I was wondering whether that was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like the following:
First define the DE in every node

```
node[1] = β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i][t],{t,2}]==M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i][t]])+τ[Θ[i+1][t],Θ[i][t]];  
node[n] = β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i][t],{t,2}]==M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i][t]])+τ[Θ[i-1][t],Θ[i][t]];  
node[i_Integer/;1$<$i$<$n] = β*M*L^2*D[Θ[i][t],{t,2}]==M*g*μ*L*(-Sin[Θ[i][t]])+τ[Θ[i-1][t],Θ[i][t]]+τ[Θ[i+1][t],Θ[i][t]];
```

Then create the system of DE

```
system = Table[node[i],{i,1,n}]
```

and then solve it

```
sol=NDSolve[Join[system, InitialConditions],Through[Array[Θ, 20][t]],{t,0,20}]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer; i'll need to read through the code first to understand it! For the while loop, I set up multiple lists containing the data, let me post it up soon.

Comment: @VincentTjeng also make more clear the action of the function g.

Comment: are the two `g` symbols clearer now? One `g` was intended to be used as the acceleration due to the earth's gravity, while the other `g` was intended just as a function that makes the expression for `τ` less complicated. I've renamed the function as `funcg`.

Comment: yes now *almost* everything is clear! ;)