# NDSolve two PDE plus one ODE, together

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a couple of PDE (time and space/length) that are correctly managed by NDSolve, but to which I’m adding an ODE on which the `acc` “accumulates”, through time, a “value” coming from one of the boundaries of the PDE (the `b*h[t, le]*u[t, le]`).

On my following example, the accumulation is not linked, and so `acc` could be calculated afterwards. But the purpose is to use the `acc[t]` value as a definition of one of the boundary of `h`. Once the errors are gone, I'll define something like `h[t, le]==acc/100` instead of the current fixed value boundary.

I’ve tried a lot of assorted stuff, but NDSolve keeps giving errors on the amount of parameters of the ODE, etc, as shown below.

I’m now thinking on managing the “accumulation” with the `EvaluationMonitoring`, but it doesn’t sound right...

```
a = 10;
le = 62;
g = 9.8;
tf = 100;
b = 3.4;
r = 5.86/le;
NDSolve[{
   b*u[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, x] + 
     b*h[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x] + 
     b*Derivative[1, 0][h][t, x] == r,

   (r*u[t, x])/(b*g*h[t, x]) + (Abs[u[t, x]]*(b + 2*h[t, x])^(4/3)*
        u[t, x])/(a^2*(b*h[t, x])^(4/3)) + 
     Derivative[0, 1][h][t, x] + (u[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x])/
      g + Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x]/g == 0,

   Derivative[1][acc][t] == b*h[t, le]*u[t, le],

   h[0, x] == 1,
   u[0, x] == 0,
   h[t, le] == 1,
   u[t, 0] == 0,
   acc[0] == 0
   },
  {u, h, acc},
  {t, 0, tf}, {x, 0, le}
  ];

  (*NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation. >>*)
```

**EDIT**

I came across a problem with the naming of the variable `acc`. But since it is probably related with a different question, I wrote my problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/ndsolve-and-c-k-slot-and-other-built-ins-as-a-variable-name/22250#22250)

Comment: As there is no direct dependence of PDE to the function acc[t], can not it be solved later as separate ODE.

Comment: @PlatoManiac as stated on the problem description, the simplified example doesn't have a dependence. But once the errors are gone, I'll add it to the h[t, le] boundary (actually, something like h[t, le]==acc/100). I just thought one problem at a time. (acc is a volume, 100 is an area, and h is a height...)

Comment: @RolfMertig but it handles well the two coupled PDE (the result looks correct when cross-checking with other sources). It's only when I add the ODE that it gets confused.

Comment: why not do Derivative[1, 0][acc][t, x] == b*h[t, le]*u[t, le] and adjust the boundary conditions

Comment: @RolfMertig I get `NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve. >>`. Since there is no "delayed" problem, I imagine that there's a different way do define it. I've done: `Derivative[1, 0][acc][t, x] == b*h[t, le]*u[t, le], acc[0, x] == 0`

Answer (score 2):

not a answer - just a elements of information - reliability not garanted

The first problem one encounters with your code is  : "NDSolve::derlen: The length of the derivative operator Derivative[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4BrT.jpg) in (acc^[Prime])[t] is not the same as the number of arguments". That's not the main problem.

To get rid of it, I have created a function acc[]` of 2 variables : t and x, and stated
the problem as 3 PDEs.

`Derivative[1][acc][t] == b*h[t, le]*u[t, le]` becomes :

`Derivative[1, 0][acc][t, x] == b*h[t, x]*u[t, x]`

Initial value `acc[t]==0` becomes : `acc[0,x]==0`

The solution of interest is acc[t,le].

Here is the code :

```
NDSolve[{
  b*u[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, x] + 
    b*h[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x] + 
    b*Derivative[1, 0][h][t, x] == r,

  (r*u[t, x])/(b*g*h[t, x]) + (Abs[u[t, x]]*(b + 2*h[t, x])^(4/3)*
       u[t, x])/(a^2*(b*h[t, x])^(4/3)) + 
    Derivative[0, 1][h][t, x] + (u[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x])/
     g + Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x]/g == 0,

  Derivative[1, 0][acc][t, x] == b*h[t, x]*u[t, x],

  h[0, x] == 1,
  u[0, x] == 0,
  h[t, le] == 1,
  u[t, 0] == 0,
  acc[0, x] == 0}, {u, h, acc}, {t, 0, tf}, {x, 0, le}]
```

Mathematica accepts this and gives this solution :

[image]

I obtain the same with your code.

Comment: It already helps a little. I'm checking if results are correct. But the definition of acc for a range of x is a little artificial, considering that acc is a single point in space... But thank you anyway.

Comment: After checking, it returns something very wrong. Probably beacuase we are relating `u` and `h` in all their x dimension with `acc`, when `acc` is actually only influencing the `le` point.

Comment: @P.Fonseca I have checked too and it seems not to be wrong. See the graphic in the answer. Is that what you expect ? Agree that the method is far from ideal. I investigate because I'm interested.

Comment: It toke me some time to figure out the problem. Take a look at my following answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/ndsolve-and-c-k-slot-and-other-built-ins-as-a-variable-name/22250#22250

Comment: P. Fonseca Thanks. Otherwise, my Mathematica version in 8.0.4.