# NDSolve: Couple PDE and ODE involving integral

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I am trying to numerically solve an equation with NDSolve, where there is a ODE coupled to a PDE, like the following:

```
    NDSolve[{
  Derivative[1, 0][u][t,x] == 
   -0.8*u[t, x] - (5.*n[t]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x])/(5. + n[t]) + (50.*n[t]^2*Derivative[0, 2][u][t, x])/(5. + n[t])^2, 
  Derivative[1][n][t] == 
   100. - 0.8*n[t] - (0.5*Integrate[u[t, x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]*n[t])/(5. + n[t]), 
  u[0, x] == 200.,
  n[0] == 50.,
  u[t, 0] == u[t, 2*Pi]},
 {u, n},
 {t, 0., 2.},
 {x, 0., 6.28}]
```

Unfortunately Mathematica tells me `"NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation"`.

When i change `n[t]` to `n[t,x]` it calculates something, but `n[t,x]` doesn't stay uniform over time, which it should because `n` wasn't a function of `x` in the first place.

Would anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Can't you just integrate your `n` function by hand and explicitly add it to the equation?

Comment: The actual problem is a little bit more complicated, so there is no formal solution for n[t]

Comment: Can you post a minimal example capturing the intricacies of the original problem then?

Comment: Sorry I can't make sense of this as there are a bunch of brackets missing, all the variables have been switched to `[Theta], [Omega]` in place of `\[Theta]`, `\[Omega]` and a constant isn't defined. You could edit the question with the full problem - that would help people get interested in this.

Comment: NDSolve[{Derivative[1, 0][u][t,x] == -0.8*u[t, x] - (5.*n[t]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x])/
     (5. + n[t]) + (50.*n[t]^2*Derivative[0, 2][u][t,x])/(5. + n[t])^2, 
  Derivative[1][n][t] == 100. - 0.8*n[t] - (0.5*Integrate[u[t,x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]*n[t])/(5. + n[t]), 
  u[0,x] == 200., n[0] == 50., u[t, 0] == u[t, 2*Pi]}, {u, n}, {t, 0., 2.}, 
 {x, 0., 6.28}]   This should be correct now.

Comment: AFAIK NDSolve can't automatically handle this, you can couple PDEs with PDEs and ODEs with ODEs but not PDEs with ODEs. But as NDSolve for all versions up to 9 uses the method by lines only for PDEs you can just as well do the method by lines by hand: generate a set of coupled ODEs by discretizaing in space and then couple that system to the single ODE. See tutorial/NDSolvePDE in the online documentation for more details, an example and even some internal helper methods which help with the discretization...

Comment: Is this related? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22189/78

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comment above, `NDSolve` doesn't know how to disretize your system, so we do it ourselves. I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the disretization of the derivative term and [Gaussian quadrature formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6966/1871) for the discretization of integral:

```
With[{u = u[t, x], n = n[t]}, 
  eq@1 = D[u, t] == -0.8 u - (5. n D[u, x])/(5. + n) + (50. n^2 D[u, x, x])/(5. + n)^2;
  eq@2 = D[n, t] == 100. - 0.8 n - (0.5 (Integrate[u, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]) n)/(5. + n);
  {ic@1, ic@2} = {u == 200, n == 5} /. t -> 0];

points = 25; difforder = 4; domain = {0, 2 Pi};

{nodes, weights} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[points, MachinePrecision]];    
midgrid = Rescale[nodes, {0, 1}, domain];

intrule = HoldPattern@
    Integrate[__] -> -Subtract @@ domain weights.Map[u[#][t] &, midgrid];

grid = Flatten[{domain[[1]], midgrid, domain[[-1]]}];

(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
  please find it in the link above.*)    
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, x], t, grid, difforder, True];
ode@1 = ptoofunc@eq@1;
ode@2 = eq@2 /. intrule;
{odeic@1, odeic@2} = {ptoofunc@ic@1, ic@2};

tend = 2;
{usollst, nsol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{ode /@ {1, 2}, odeic /@ {1, 2}}, {u /@ grid, n}, {t, 0, tend}];
usol = rebuild[usollst, grid];
```

Notice the periodic b.c. is set with the 5th argument of `pdetoode`.

```
Plot3D[usol[t, x], {t, 0, tend}, {x, ##}] & @@ domain
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[nsol[t], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]