# NDSolve a system of one PDE coupled with an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I would like to solve a partial differential equation where one of the boundary conditions is the solution of an ordinary differential equation that is coupled to the partial differential equation.  From two related questions ([question#1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46146/ndsolve-couple-ode-and-pde?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [question#2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/ndsolve-two-pde-plus-one-ode-together)), it is not clear if this is possible using NDSolve.

While the code below does not work, it best illustrates what I would like to do and is similar to what is found in [question#1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46146/ndsolve-couple-ode-and-pde?noredirect=1&lq=1).  I have tried to modify the code similar to what was done in [question#2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/ndsolve-two-pde-plus-one-ode-together), but none of the changes I have tried seemed to work.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem with Mathematica?

```
(*constants*)
initialvalue = 300.;
outervalue = 300.;
c1 = 11.025;(*RI^2*)
c2 = 1.*10^-7;(*contact resistance*)
c3 = 4.7*10^-7;(*contact area*)
c4 = 0.0000258;(*massWire*heatCapacityWire*)
d1 = 0.0000113;(*zpp Diffusivity*)
d2 = 4600.;(*zppDensity*)
d3 = 250.;(*zppCp*)

(*source term*)
source[temp_] := 9.37*10^25*Exp[-29226./temp];

(*ranges*)
rmin = 0.00003;
rmax = 0.01;
tmin = 0.0;
tmax = 0.02;

(*equations*)
eqn1 = D[tempc[r, t], t] == d1 (D[tempc[r, t], {r, 2}] + (1/r) D[tempc[r, t], r]) + source[tempc[r, t]]/d2/d3;

eqn2 = D[tempw[t], t] == c4*(c1 - c3 (tempw[t] - tempc[rmin, t])/c2);

(*boundary conditions*)
bcOuter = tempc[rmax, t] == outervalue;

(*initial conditions*)
icw = tempw[0.] == initialvalue;
icc = tempc[r, 0.] == initialvalue;

(*solve system*)
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcOuter, icw, icc}, {tempc, tempw}, {r, rmin, rmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, Compiled -> True]
```

I appreciate any suggestions or tips you can provide!

Comment: What is the `rmin` boundary condition and how is it related to `tempw[t]`?

Comment: The `rmin` boundary condition for `tempc[r,t]` comes from solving `eqn2` for `tempc[rmin,t]`.  That is how the ODE should be coupled into the rmin boundary condition of the PDE.

Comment: Then, how is `tempw[t]` determined?  `eqn2` cannot be used to determine both.

Comment: The two unknowns that I have are `tempw[t]` and `tempc[r,t]`.  I have two equations coupling the two unknowns so the problem is soluble.  It really is no different than a solving a system of coupled PDEs (or ODEs) using NDSolve, it's just this time it is a PDE coupled to an ODE. Also, I have solved it already explicitly using a forward-time central-space (FTCS) finite difference method.  The problem is this FTCS method is slow in Mathematica and I would like to speed it up using NDSolve, if possible.

Comment: Is it the case that `tempc[rmin, t] == tempw[t]`?  I ask this, because this equation is not included in your question, and it (or something similar) is necessary in order to provide a boundary condition for `tempc` at `rmin`.  With such a boundary condition, the system of equations can be solved as described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1699661144), with the equation for `tempc[rmin, t]` replace by the equation for `tempw[t]`.

Comment: The boundary condition is almost that simple, but not quite.  What we have at that boundary is `tempc[rmin, t] == tempw[t] - (c2 / c3)(c1-D[tempw[t], t] / c4)`.  With the finite difference scheme I mentioned previously, `tempw[t]` is calculated using values from the previous time step and it is then straight forward to approximate  `D[tempw[t], t]` from `(tempw[tcurrent] - tempw[tprevious])/dt`.

Comment: No.  As I stated in an earlier comment, if  `eqn2` is used to specify `tempc[rmin, t]`, then a different equation must be provided to specify how `tempw[t]` evolves in time.