# Variable naming changes everything

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, bugs, version-9, letter-makes-difference

**Bug fixed in 10.0.0**

---

I am having a rather unusual problem I do not understand with Mathematica where renaming one of the variables of my function causes the function to stop "working". Here is the example of the code doing what it should:

```
F[t_, a_, b_, l_] = x[t] /. First@
DSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - (x[t]/b)) - l*x[t], x[0] == 0.4}, x[t], t];
```

Changing one variable name causes the code to throw out error messages. The non-working code is

```
F[t_, r_, b_, l_] = x[t] /. First@ DSolve[{x'[t] == r*x[t]*(1 -
(x[t]/b)) - l*x[t], x[0] == 0.4}, x[t], t];
```

Comment: A very peculiar bug. It works if `r` is replaced by any of `a`, `c`, `d`, or `e`, but chokes for the other letters. What version and OS are you using, for reference?

Comment: It seems that only variables that begin with `a` `c` `d` `e` will work (something like `aaa` is also OK)… very strange!

Comment: @J.M. I'm thinking about something to do with the lexicographical order of `E`

Comment: For what it's worth a lot of information is returned with `Trace[. . ., TraceInternal -> True]` for anyone who has the time and energy to dig through it.

Comment: Version: 9.0.1.0. OS: Windows 7.

Comment: @5xum Did you report this to support@wolfram.com as bug?  Please do if you haven't yet and link back to this question.

Comment: @Szabolcs I reported it, will report when anything happens. It's CASE:134234 by the way

Comment: @5xum, is the ticket publically viewable? So we could track status change.

Comment: Another case (MathGroups): "[very odd failure of Solve](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/nUp0dV-HPTc/i9g2k0lNRs0J)."

Comment: Other cases http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22250/78

Comment: [Another related post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19322/1871)

Comment: Seems solved in 10.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little bit more. Still not fully diagnosed, but the problem isn't due to `DSolve`
 ... :

```
s1 = DSolve[{x'[t] == f*x[t] (1 - (x[t]/b)) - l x[t]}, x[t], t];
s2 = DSolve[{x'[t] == e*x[t] (1 - (x[t]/b)) - l x[t]}, x[t], t];
```

And the problem shows up when matching the initial condition:

```
Solve[(x[t] /. s2[[1]] /. t -> 0) == 4/10, C[1]]
(*
{{C[1] -> -(Log[1/2 (2 e - 5 b e + 5 b l)]/(b (e - l)))}}
*)
```

but

```
Solve[(x[t] /. s1[[1]] /. t -> 0) == 4/10, C[1]]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

BTW,

```
Solve[(x[t] /. s1[[1]] /. t -> 0) == 4/10, C[1], Reals]
```

can be solved without any problem

**Edit**

I was able to track down the problem to:

```
Solve[E^(a w) (f - e) == E^(b w), {w}]
```

and

```
Solve[E^(a w) (f - g) == E^(b w), {w}]
```

only the first one gives a result!

Comment: Wow. I was sure I was missing something completely obvious, but the chaotic behavior makes me think this is just a very bizzare bug...

Comment: @5xum Not obvious at all ...

Comment: cant solve this regardless of etters..Solve[E^(a w) (f - 1 ) == E^w, {w}]

Comment: @5xum An apparent bug indeed, and one that has persisted at least from version 7 through version 9.  I'm surprised this hasn't been found and addressed in that time.

Comment: A more simplified one: `Solve[E^(a w) (b - 1) == E^w, w]`.

Comment: @Silvia Sorry, changing which letter does it turn solvable?

Comment: I can't find a setting which makes it work.. But I believe it's the some issue. btw I traced to a ``System`Private`OldSolve`` function..

Comment: @Silvia Oh, I see now. Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is a plain bug, a pattern matching messup that makes MMA think it can solve one expression and not the other. It's funny how it can solve the last example only if at least one of the two variables you add or subtract is sorted before the letter `E` (or whatever you put as base to that power)

Comment: @Silvia Try the `Solve[]` with  `MaxExtraConditions -> All`

Comment: Wow didn't know this option! Thanks!

Comment: @5xum If we can narrow down the bug to a specific set of variables, then it would be nice if the accepted answer patches(well monkey patches the issue) the issue maybe using `Replace`

Answer (score 7):

The problem can be reduced to the `DSolve` expressions:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - (x[t]/b)) - l*x[t], x[0] == 0.4}, x[t], t]

DSolve[{x'[t] == h*x[t]*(1 - (x[t]/b)) - l*x[t], x[0] == 0.4}, x[t], t]
```

One can see that alphabetical order appears important:

```
With[{a = Symbol@#},
  Shallow @ DSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - (x[t]/b)) - l*x[t], x[0] == 0.4}, x[t], t]
] & /@ DeleteCases[CharacterRange["a", "z"], "b" | "l" | "t" | "x"]
```

> ```
> {{{Rule[<<2>>]}}, {{Rule[<<2>>]}}, {{Rule[<<2>>]}}, {{Rule[<<2>>]}}, {}, {}, {},
>   {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
> ```

I suspect that this may be related to: [Why does Simplify ignore an assumption?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/121)
Unfortunately I cannot think of a robust way to address the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Definitely, interesting.

Comment: Finally I have a justifiable reason for using `aardvark` as a variable name :-)

Comment: @SimonWoods You might then be interested in [AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/AAAAAAAAA!) :D

Comment: @SimonWoods `DSolve[{ax'[at] == ah*ax[at]*(1 - (ax[at]/ab)) - l*ax[at], ax[0] == 0.4}, 
 ax[at], at]` seems to work...

Comment: If you want to "address" the problem in a robust way (as opposed to "diagnosing" the  cause of the bug), I think that  `SetOptions[Solve,MaxExtraConditions -> All]` may help

Comment: @belisarius I don't think that option is present in Version 7, unless undocumented.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was introduced in 8 to cope with some V7 inconsistency http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/325718