# Are greek symbols causing different evaluation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, symbols, letter-makes-difference

I've updated today to Mathematica 9.0.1.0 from version 8 and found something that absolutely confuses me.
Let us define a piecewise function:

```
gr[x_, v1_, v2_, v3_, v4_, v5_] = 
Piecewise[{{g, v1 < x < v1+v2}, {g, v1+v3 < x < v1+v2+v3}, 
{gs, v1+v2+v3+v4 < x < v1+v3+v2+v4+v5}}, 0]
```

and try integrating it with obvious assumptions:

```
Integrate[gr[x, a, b, c, d, e], {x, 0, END}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < a < a+b < a+c < a+b+c < a+b+c+d < a+b+c+d+e < END}]
```

This takes around 60 seconds and obviously results in `2 b g + e gs` (although it seems it was a lot faster in Mathematica 8, though it's not the point here). Now, if we do the very same integration, but with different symbols:

```
Integrate[gr[x, τ, δ, Δ, τs, δs], {x, 0, TR}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < τ < τ+δ < τ+Δ < τ+δ+Δ < τ+δ+Δ+τs < τ+δ+Δ+τs+δs < TR}]
```

All of a sudden this doesn't evaluate in 60 seconds, running till it pages all the memory available and crashing afterwads. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Interesting. Make a simpler version, use a symbol for the lower integration limit also, add them and the variables involved in the assumptions as `Reals`: MMA generates same result, but with *wildy* convoluted conditions when using greeks vs non, along with taking longer.

Comment: Maybe a similar issue of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25182/1871)? BTW, confirmed in v8.0.4 too.

Comment: Looks like a similar issue. Now, tested it on 8.0.4.0 too, the non-Greek expression evaluates a bit faster, but that's probably due to a faster hardware. Also, actually no need to replace all the variables with Greek letters, just swapping `a` for `τ` is sufficient to stop the expression from evaluating.

Comment: It's not about greek or not greek. It's about the sorting of the symbols. Some of these functions which, theoretically, should be invariant to that, are not. There was another question around, perhaps related to `Solve`

Comment: They (the present example and the `Solve` one) are similar issues. At heart, as noted by @Rojo, it has to do with internal ordering having an impact on simplification, cylindrical decomposition, and other under-the-hood functionality that is called upon by the likes of `Integrate` and `Solve`. We'll look into these examples but I am doubtful as to whether they are readily remediated.

Comment: Interestingly, when running the greek-letter code on 10.0.2.0, after a short time I see two kernels running, one consuming an ever-increasing amount of memory, both running with full CPU-load, and **both keeping on running, even if the evaluation has been aborted in the frontend**.

Has anybody experienced a similar behavior?

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior Jinxed has mentioned. It rails one of my CPUs but, more interestingly, leaks memory indefinitely. I quit after it gobbled up 12GB of RAM (the system was totally responsive, so quitting the local kernel was fine). Unless I saw wrong, of the two kernels, the one eating memory was not CPU intensive.

Answer (score 4):

I think Daniel Lichtblau gave a useful answer in his comment. This is to get it on record.

> They (the present example and the Solve one) are similar issues. At heart, as noted by @Rojo, it has to do with internal ordering having an impact on simplification, cylindrical decomposition, and other under-the-hood functionality that is called upon by the likes of Integrate and Solve. We'll look into these examples but I am doubtful as to whether they are readily remediated