# Two identical functions give different answers

Tags: function-construction

I am new to mathematica and I hope this is a simple problem. I have two identical functions that only differ by the variable names:

```
PolarInverseFT[f_, p_, u_, r_, t_] := 
 Integrate[
  p f Exp[-I 2 π r p Cos[u - t]], {p , 0, ∞}, {u, 0, 2 π} ]

PolarInverseFT2[f_, r_, t_, p_, u_] := 
 Integrate[
  r f Exp[-I 2 π  p r Cos[t - u]], {r, 0, ∞}, {t, 0, 2 π} ]
```

I would expect them to behave identically. However,

```
PolarInverseFT[λ^2/(λ^2 + 4 π^2 p^2), p, u, r, t]
```

returns the error

> -I Sin[2 p π r #1] is not a valid variable

But

```
PolarInverseFT2[λ^2/(λ^2 + 4 π^2 r^2), r, t, p, u]
```

gives the correct answer. For other f_ both can return an answer without failing, but the answers differ!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: In general, why including your integration variables in the arguments ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks that was my first thought as well. The integration variables appear in the first argument, so this makes sense ( the second and third arguments in each case  *must be* passed in as undefined symbols ).   That said, I obtain different results for the two cases, starting with a clean kernel each time. (not the same error though, the first case returns an unevaluated integral w/v9)

Comment: @b.gatessucks True, but besides the point. I note that the integrals themselves (executed directly and not through the above definitions) exhibit the same strange behavior.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries There was a question about something very similar, but I can't find it right now. The problem was caused by the lexicographical ordering of the symbol names, as strange as it may seem. Do you remember that question?

Comment: @belisarius I remember two questions that were related, Daniel lichtblau commented there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries [Related 1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43108/are-greek-symbols-causing-different-evaluation) and [Related 2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25182/variable-naming-changes-everything)

Comment: confirmed the lexicographical ordering of the symbol names being subtracted for the  `Cos` argument is the distinction here.  Interestingly changing to `Cos[u+t]` fixes it.

Comment: @george2079 It's more interesting if you also consider that `FullForm@Cos[u - t] == FullForm@Cos[t - u]`

Comment: @belisarius: And gets even more interesting, if you reverse the integration parameters: All of a sudden, FT2 yields 0, while FT1 runs on and on and on (and then stops without any result, but some (other) General::ivar errors).

Comment: A simpler way to trigger the General::ivar messages: `Integrate[Exp[-I Cos[u - t]], {u, 0, 2*Pi}]`.  The result from this Integrate is correct, but the messages shouldn't be there.

Comment: I believe that you should remove `p_` and `u_` from the arguments to `PolarInverseFT` as they are used as limit variables for the integration. Similarly remove `r_` and `t_` from the arguments to `PolarInverseFT2`. I don't think this will fix your problem but I think the code is better.

Answer (score 1):

not an answer, just a simpler demonstration of the issue ( version 9.01 )

```
Integrate[r (1/(1 + 4 Pi^2 r^2)) Exp[-I 2 Pi  r Cos[t - u]],
       {r, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

In the second case I've just copied the expression and changed `t` to `z` ..
puzzling. It seems in the first case `u` has been assumed real and the second not.

Comment: In 10.0.0 both expressions return the (same) unevaluated integral.

Comment: This should probably just be a comment...

Comment: 10.1 gives a different second answer to 9.0.1